# asp.net validation control for only TEXT input

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, .net-3.5

What validation control would I need if I want the user to enter only TEXT characters in a textbox and what would be the validation expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use an ASP.NET component to do this, it's the RegEx validator.  Plug this in as the expression, it will only allow alpha characters, which is what I assume you mean by TEXT.

> ^[a-zA-Z]*$